# Volume mount and environment variable access for a Window service running in a container in kubernetes

Tags: windows, kubernetes, containers

An application that runs as a Windows service in a Windows container (without any overrides for run-as user - `New-Service -Name x -BinaryPath someservice.exe` step in the container build) is expecting an environment variable set on the container as well as read a file mounted in the container.  I know that I can run applications directly via the entrypoint and they are able to read the env variable and file from mount, but as a service I am getting errors indicating it isn't.

Are environment variables scoped to user by default, would something like a RunAs configuration in security context be needed, or some other mechanism? Or would there be any limitations on access to file mounts by the service?

**edit**
Investigate the environment variables a bit more, seems like this might be the part that's missing. I tried to echo a var based on specific scopes:

```
PS C:\dir> echo ([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("varname","User"))
PS C:\dir> echo ([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("varname","Machine"))
PS C:\dir> echo ([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("varname","Process"))
expected_value
```

So I suspect the service doesn't have access to the process. Am going to try rescoping the variable:
`[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('varname',$env:varname,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)`

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem

Comment: Am running it in AWS using EKS.

Comment: Please answer my question about your Kubernetes version. Could you provide your yaml files? Where exactly do you have a problem?

Comment: The issue wasn't with kubernetes, it was more to do with how windows works with scope of variables, for entrypoint processes vs Windows services. The env vars from kuberenetes are scoped to `Process` which a Windows Service does not have access to. By using powershell in the entrypoint to set a `Machine` scoped variable from the process-scoped one, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related due to environment variable scoping - the environment variables passed to the container are `Process` scoped. However, if a Windows service is started in the container, it does not have access to the scope (the entrypoint process does).

In order to resolve this, I set entrypoint to a powershell wrapper for the app that copied the Process scope environment variable to the Machine scope before starting the Windows service:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('varname',$env:varname,[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
# start service command.
```